# Weasyprint Dockerfile for GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, weasyprint

I am trying to install weasyprint on gae, i know we can install external libraries by passing it in a Dockerfile by changing the runtime from python to custom in app.yaml. I am having trouble creating the Dockerfile for weasyprint libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple **example** that I wrote following [these](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-runtime#kubernetes-engine--other-docker-hosts) instructions. I have tested it and the deployment on GAE has been successful for me:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/python

# Create a virtualenv for dependencies. This isolates these packages from
# system-level packages.
# Use -p python3 or -p python3.7 to select python version. Default is version 2.
RUN virtualenv /env -p python3.7

# Setting these environment variables are the same as running
# source /env/bin/activate.
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV /env
ENV PATH /env/bin:$PATH

# Install platform's packages required for WeasyPrint
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install build-essential python3-dev python3-pip \
python3-setuptools python3-wheel python3-cffi \
libcairo2 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libffi-dev shared-mime-info

# Copy the application's requirements.txt and run pip to install all
# dependencies into the virtualenv.
ADD requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Add the application source code.
ADD . /app

# Run a WSGI server to serve the application. gunicorn must be declared as
# a dependency in requirements.txt.
CMD gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app
```

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
```

**rquirements.txt**

```
gunicorn==19.1.1
Flask==1.0.2
WeasyPrint>=0.34
```

**main.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from weasyprint import *


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Success!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080)
```

---

**Note** that as WeasyPrint [documentation](https://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html) mentions, platform's packages *(such as cairo, Pango and GDK-PixBuf)* must be installed separately. They are installed with the following command I added in the Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install build-essential python3-dev python3-pip python3-setuptools python3-wheel python3-cffi libcairo2 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libffi-dev shared-mime-info
```

Comment: set `weasyprint==52.5` in requirements.txt for this to keep working, this is a great answer thx!