# How to install libraries on Google App Engine for Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-app-engine, gcloud, weasyprint

I have a Python3 project currently hosted on GCloud. I'm looking to enhance this project by allowing report generation based on a template. I'm investigating WeasyPrint.

The thing about WeasyPrint is that it has a lot of requirements required to manually install that can't be done through `pip`. One particular one is **GDK-PixBuf**, which not only require a `sudo-install` (?), but also references to `PATH` in the environment variable.

I'm a relative newbie to GCloud deployment and I'm not sure how to do this in the GCloud server, hence my (initial) reluctance to use WeasyPrint.

On top of that, while reading on on how to do this, [Google themselves only has documentation for it in Python2 which says it(and Cairo) are not supported](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#matplotlib), nothing about Python 3, which is further confusing me.

[The Python3 documentation itself is not helping much.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/specifying-dependencies)

I found something with regards to this, but aside from its age, [it's more catered towards Python2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850853/how-to-include-third-party-python-libraries-in-google-app-engine).

Comment: have you tried something like the Python Client for Google Cloud Storage to leverage a working solution? [link] https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/index.html

Comment: Cant say I understand what you mean. Also, I dont think that helps.

Comment: I was able to install WeasyPrint on Google Colab which is also on G Cloud. Most of the dependencies are installed as part of that. LIke you mentioned GDK-PixBuf is not being covered, however you can still do a install using this [link] http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/gdk-pixbuf/2.40/gdk-pixbuf-2.40.0.tar.xz and for path reference you need to move your python.exe setup file to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use WeasyPrint in **GAE standard** as it is dependent on some C-based packages (e.g. cairo, Pango, GDK-PixBuf), which the GAE's Python runtime is lacking - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23105685/how-to-get-weasyprint-working-with-google-app-engine).

However, you could use the **GAE flexible** environment as it allows using custom runtimes. In GAE flexible you can install the required components through the Dockerfile. Please see the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61600712/weasyprint-dockerfile-for-gae/61636670#61636670) I wrote some time ago on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

App Engine standard does not let you install additional software beyond things `pip` can do for you, so I don't think it can meet your needs. App Engine flexible does allow that, but I think [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run) would be a better fit and easier to learn and use. Cloud Run has you specify a container that it then builds, deploys, and manages in response to web requests. You can install the needed binaries and set the PATH when the container is built.

See the [Cloud Run quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy) for Python for an example Dockerfile that shows how to set environment variables and run Linux commands (such as installing needed software) during build time.